# Scala: folding on Stream of fibonacci numbers

Tags: scala, fibonacci, fold

I am trying to make a function in Scala that takes an Integer argument and returns the addition of the fibonacci numbers up to the given fib. number. I'm using a Stream to get the fib. numbers, then folding right to add them. Why does this produce a stack overflow, and how can I fix it?

```
def fibonacci(n: Int): Long = {
lazy val f: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: (f.zip(f.tail)).map{t=>t._1 + t._2}.filter(_<=n)
f.foldRight(0)(_+_).toLong
}
```

For example, entering 5, I would expect 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 = **12**

Comment: Obviously you got yourself a recursion that never terminated.

Comment: The most concise Fibonacci Stream I've encountered: `def fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1)(_+_)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `stackoverflow` is caused by `.filter(_<=n)`, `filter` need to iterate all **fibonaci** numbers list generated by `0 #:: 1 #:: (f.zip(f.tail)).map{t=>t._1 + t._2}`.

Maybe you want:

```
0 #:: 1 #:: (f.zip(f.tail)).map{t=>t._1 + t._2}.takeWhile(_ <= n)
```

**takeWhile** will return matched predicate numbers directly and abort to iterate the other numbers.

Comment: One issue though...why do fibonacci(5), fibonacci(6), fibonacci(7), fibonacci(8) all return 12?

Comment: `5, 6, 7` they all have same fibonacci numbers: `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5`, but for `8` should be: `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8`, can you check your `fibonacci(8)` again?

Comment: fibonacci(8) still returns 12

Comment: okay, I had takeWhile(_< n), rather than <=, so 8 was really evaluated as 7. fibonacci(8) now returns 20